# Embedding child components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying the most basic of tasks: creating a parent component that calls in a child component using react.js.

Here's my parent component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import PanelTop from './PanelTop.jsx';

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <PanelTop/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Card/>, document.getElementById("card"));
```

Apparently, `return <PanelTop/>` is throwing the following error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of Card`

`PanelTop.jsx` contains:

```
import React from 'react';

export class PanelTop extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div class="panel" id="panelTop"><button>Click Me!</button></div>
  }
}
```

Obviously I'm missing something, like how imports and exports work in ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you need export `PanelTop` class(it is called [`Named exports`](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#named_exports_%28several_per_module%29)) from `PanelTop.jsx`, like this

```
import { PanelTop } from './PanelTop.jsx';
```

or use [`default exports`](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default_exports_%28one_per_module%29) in `PanelTop.jsx`

```
export default class PanelTop extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
```